# Delineating training on a mesh for CGAL classification

Tags: classification, mesh, cgal

Is there a mechanism/procedure in CGAL to delineate training samples on a mesh for classification? I note that it is documented in the demo files but not how the training labels were generated.

(eg using the ETHZ R.Fores)

Using the Polyhedron_3 demo I can do this for points but not for a mesh it appears.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a mesh, you can do it similarly in the demo, but you have to use the mesh selection plugin (in facet mode) instead of point set selection one. Apart from that, it's all the same, you just need to select facets and add them to the training set.